# Convert dynamic class by state value from react to typescript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I need to use this react function, but in typescript

```
const ListItem = ({ text }) => {
    let [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className="item">
            <div>
                <div className={`text ${showMore ? "active" : ""}`}>{text}</div>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => setShowMore((s) => !s)}>Show more</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I have tried something like this, but i am getting some errors

```
<html>TS2345: Argument of type '(s: showContent) =&gt; boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction&lt;showContent&gt;'.<br/>Type '(s: showContent) =&gt; boolean' is not assignable to type '(prevState: showContent) =&gt; showContent'.<br/>Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'showContent'.
```

```
interface showContent {
  state: boolean;
}

let [showMore, setShowMore] = React.useState<showContent>({ state: false });

    return (
        <div className="item">
            <div>
                <div className={`text ${showMore ? "active" : ""}`}>{text}</div>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => setShowMore((s) => !s)}>Show more</button>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Sorry didn't read you second code block. You didn't update your setState call to match your interface. `() => setShowMore((s) => ({state: !s.state}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Conversion to typescript

If your intention was to convert the first block to typescript, then you do not need the `showContent` interface as you're only providing a boolean value.

```
import React, { ReactNode, useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  text: ReactNode;
}

const ListItem = ({ text }: Props) => {
    let [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className="item">
            <div>
                <div className={`text ${showMore ? "active" : ""}`}>{text}</div>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => setShowMore((s) => !s)}>Show more</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

See [this Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJktgK4DOSAyjCjEnAL5wBmUEIcARFARi8A3AFgAUBOAA7JlHbpmABS5gquCXDhMAHjABc+dDGJkx4lhIloI0qvAAywewEkmPALxwAFHl3wWQxUINQBKOA8APg1xLS0AGyR4AG0qAAsIAHcAWWhyOBoYWgycvIBdCLhqOgYmbwV4mlDzTTiBGAooaR9WuLiAHhJgADc4NHiUKipCFBAkD15gd15I3r71wZHV2PXdvs3R8cnp2fmcAAN-OAASHHSs3IE4AH4+YxGkXjhDXl4Wc5YkRw-hY-QA9ENhts9hsIVs1jD+gAjCgwGC2OC2ADC8WAaAA1h4cN5wlECklig88t5vFRSdEAIR0wGUzJwEB5cEotG2aF7cGQvlaZoSFjCIA)

## About the error

The error you were getting:

> Argument of type '(s: showContent) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.
> Type '(s: showContent) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(prevState: showContent) => showContent'.
> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'showContent'.(2345)

Is trying to tell you that you cannot assign a `boolean` (meaning `true` or `false`) to an object with signature `{ state: boolean; }`. This is why @pilchard suggested to create an object to match your interface (`{ state: !s.state }`).

But as the code shows above, I don't think you need this object at all, it seems like a typing mistake.